# Чтение переменных, разделённых пробелом

Tags: java

```
376 3899 488000
```

Знакомо? Это так дают входные данные в олимпиадных задачках.

Помню на паскале был какой то read():

```
read(a,b,c);
```

И мы имеем a = 378, b = 3899, c = 488000

А есть что нибудь такое в java? Или надо обязательно считывать строку и ручками её разделять?

Comment: Есть, конечно. Знакомьтесь, [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отгуглил: Sacnner.nextInt() и его подобки